# What am I? Seasonal riddle

Tags: riddle

I am white
Have some things brown
And something orange

My form is mostly round
But stems from imaginations

And when the time comes
I wither away
Until such a time
When they again can play

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A snowman.

Because

I am white, Have some things brown, And something orange

> Orange = carrot nose, 
>  Some things brown = twigs/branches for arms.

My form is mostly round, But stems from imaginations

> Round = form of the sections making up a snowman,

And when the time comes
I wither away
Until such a time
When they again can play

> Withering away = melting in spring.

Comment: That was ludicrously quick :O well done :p

Comment: I literally have to wait to accept your answer :/

Comment: Sorry. was watching stackexchange main site live feed, and spotted it pop up. I'm new here - am I supposed to hide that in a Spoiler box?

Comment: It would be nice, but perhaps the question is easy enough that people won't wonder too long...it is your decision :) and welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I improved the format for you, you can review it if you want. Its common here to answer in a spoiler box so other users can answer the same question.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, Marco! I will remember to add spoilers in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> A Snowman

---

"Seasonal Riddle" and "I am white" phrase make me think of Winter.
Then found it suited as below, 
Brown - A snowman's coat 
Orange - His nose 
Round - His body 
It is not always existed and will be melted in a time.  
We can built it again when we like to play!

---

It's kinda easy riddle. :D

Comment: Yes I think the title pretty much gave it away :D will be more mysterious next time :p